# Creating service in React Typescript using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, javascript-objects

There are two different ways to create a service and call from the required funtional component.

1.

```
export const userProfileService = {

    ResetPassword: async (userId: string) => {
        var response = await http.get<string, boolean>(`UserProfile/ResetPassword?userId=${userId}`);
        return response;
    }
}
```

2. 

```
class UserProfileService {

    readonly userProfilePath = 'UserProfile';

    resetPassword = async (userId: string) => {
        var response = await http.get<string, boolean> 
      (`${this.userProfilePath}/ResetPassword?userId=${userId}`);
        return response;
    }
    export default new UserProfileService();


**The question is which way is better and optimized way? or better convention?**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just make it a function?

```
export const resetPassword: async (userId: string) => {
         return await http.get<string, boolean>(`UserProfile/ResetPassword?userId=${userId}`);
    }
```

Putting the function in a class or an object seems to only complicate and obfuscate in this case. It looks very much like a C#-influenced style. Not terrible or wrong per se, but a bit verbose and complicated when all you need is a pure function.

Also, you should use `let` or `const` keyword instead of `var` because of differences in scope. You're not making any errors in the code above because `var` is function-scoped, but it's almost always better to use `const` (or `let` if you need to modify it).

Comment: I required to put multiple methods under userProfileService. @Emanuel Lindström